# Create a HTML element with ReactJs

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to learn ReactJS and now I'm making a small project that consists of a button that every time I click it, it will show an html element (as I still couldn't get the button to work, I haven't created the element yet, so the element it should create is an h1), but when I click the button nothing happens, could anyone help me? (sorry for any spelling mistakes, I'm still learning English)
This is my code:

```
import Container from "./App.style";

import Button from "./Components/Button/Button.jsx";

const App = ()  => {
  const createElement = () => {
    return(
      <h1>Hey</h1>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
          <h1>Criador De Elementos</h1>
          <Button onClick={ createElement }>Criar Elemento</Button>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";

import StylesButton from "./Button.style";

const Button = ( {onClick, children} ) => {
    return ( 
        <StylesButton onClick={ onClick }> { children } </StylesButton>
     );
}
 
export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you your code is correct. But my question is where you want to that h1 element. If you want h1 to Your DOM than you must create an h1 to your DOM and control value of h1 by using state (by Using useState Hook).

if you want to render your h1 element then you can do like this.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import Container from "./App.style";

import Button from "./Components/Button/Button.jsx";

const App = ()  => {
  const [heading,setHeading] = useState("");

  const createElement = () => {
    setHeading("Hey");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
          <h1>Criador De Elementos</h1>
          <Button onClick={ createElement }>Criar Elemento</Button>
          <h1>{heading}</h1>

      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
import React from "react";

import StylesButton from "./Button.style";

const Button = ( {onClick, children} ) => {
    return ( 
        <StylesButton onClick={ onClick }> { children } </StylesButton>
     );
}
 
export default Button;
```

Comment: Welcome @EduardWild. if you want to learn more about state (useState) and you can use official react [documentation] (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)